# Why might Express error handling middleware not receive req.session?

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

**Environment:** node.js, Express, express-session package.

**Background:** I was testing an Express error handler and I got an error that I wasn't expecting.

The following simplified route throws an error.

> *TypeError: Cannot read property 'userValues' of undefined*

```
exports.errorHandler = wrapAsync(async function(error, req, res, next) {

    let loggedIn = req.session.userValues ? true : false;

    res.render('error', { loggedIn });
});
```

However when I remove the `error` parameter it works without an error as I had anticipated.

```
exports.errorHandler = wrapAsync(async function(req, res, next) {

    let loggedIn = req.session.userValues ? true : false;

    res.render('error', { loggedIn });
});
```

Why might this be?

The basic pattern in the second example works in several dozen routes that don't include the error parameter.

Comment: Where and how do you use the `errorHandler`? It should be the last function that gets called

Comment: @midrizi normally it's the bottom of the stack.  For testing purposes I made a `get` route to view the rendered ejs.  `router.get('/error', middleware.errorHandler);`

Comment: Firstly there is no point on making it `asynchronous` and second of all you cannot assign that to a `route` it's meant for `error` [error-handling](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this. And it will only get executed whenever there is an `ERROR 500` unless you passed the `ERROR 404` to this one using `next()` function, if you handled all the errors correctly you should be able to make an `ERROR 500` and this should be able to `catch` that `ERROR`.

```js
const errorHandler = require("./your-file");

...
... every other route even error 404 handler
...

app.use(errorHandler);
```

What do I mean by using `next()` for `ERROR 404`

If you have used `express-generator` then you should already have this piece of `code`:

```js
// catch 404 and forward to error handle
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    next('not found');
});
```

The end file should looks something like this now if you use this approach:

```
...
... all previous routes
...

// catch 404 and forward to error handle
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    next('not found');
});

// handle all other error
app.use(errorHandler);
```

***Hope this helps***